# Serverless: Configuration error at root: unrecognized property 'stepFunctions'

Tags: amazon-web-services, serverless, aws-step-functions, localstack

I have some strange errors and I can not find out the reason, can you help me?

> ...
> Serverless: Warning: Unable to find plugin named: TypeScriptPlugin
> Serverless: Configuration error at root: unrecognized property 'stepFunctions'
> ...

**serverless.yml**

```
service:
  name: service-name

plugins:
  - serverless-localstack
  - serverless-step-functions
  - serverless-pseudo-parameters
  - serverless-webpack

custom:
  webpackIncludeModules: true
  localstack:
    stages:
      - local
    host: http://localhost
    edgePort: 4566
    autostart: true
    lambda:
      mountCode: false
    debug: true
    docker:
      sudo: true

provider:
  configValidationMode: off
  deploymentBucket:
    name: local
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs12.x
  stage: ${opt:stage, "dev"}
  region: ${env:AWS_REGION, "us-east-1"}
  logRetentionInDays: 30

functions:
  ...

stepFunctions:
  ...
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "service-name",
  "version": "0.119.0",
  "description": "Service decription.",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "^7.2.0",
    "babel-core": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.5",
    "babel-plugin-source-map-support": "^2.0.1",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.6.1",
    "serverless": "^1.40.0",
    "serverless-localstack": "^0.4.27",
    "serverless-pseudo-parameters": "^1.4.2",
    "serverless-step-functions": "^1.11.0",
    "serverless-webpack": "^4.4.0",
    "webpack": "^3.11.0",
    "webpack-node-externals": "^1.6.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-runtime": "^6.26.0",
    "source-map-support": "^0.5.9"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is just a bug with the package `serverless-step-functions`

This can be resolved by updating the library :)

```
"serverless-step-functions": "^2.23.x",
```